# ErrorHandling in Yii

Tags: php, yii, error-handling

I have developed a web application using Yii, but I can't rich error handling solution.

This is my code

config/main.php

```
'components'=>array(
   'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
),
```

SiteController

```
public function actionError()
{

    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        {
            echo $error['message'];

        }
        else
            $this->render('error', array('error'=>$error));
    }
}
```

Then not work

Showing

[image: Showing]

How can I reach this solution?

Comment: rename error to error1 and try again

Comment: Above image are same, but change text `The system is unable to find the requested action "error1".`

Comment: check accessrule function of controller?

Comment: Hi now I show error page properly, but above error showing below error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved Itself.

How to solved this problem

Add error function on the inside accessRules function

And comment config/main.php

```
/* array(
    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
    'enabled'=>defined('YII_DEBUG'),
  ), */
```

That's it

Hope help anyone